# Cannot execute screenfetch

Tags: command-line, scripts, execute-command

I have downloaded screenfetch in one directory I make.

```
mkdir ~/screenfetch
wget -O screenfetch 'https://raw.github.com/KittyKatt/screenFetch/master/screenfetch-dev'
chmod +x screenfetch
./screenfetch
```

It sucessfully works inside this dir. Then I wanted to execute it in wide system.

```
sudo cp -r screenfetch /usr/local/bin
```

But it does not work when I execute it elsewhere (except in **`~/screenfetch`** and /**`usr/local/bin`**). This is what I get

```
$ screenfetch -s

Command 'screenfetch' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install screenfetch
```

The output of `file /usr/local/bin/screenfetch`:

```
/usr/local/bin/screenfetch: directory
```

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: Did you mistype `local`? What is the output of `echo $PATH`?

Comment: @Kulfy it is `/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games
`

Comment: @Kulfy ohh yes sorry for my wrong tpye. I have edited it !

Comment: Are you sure that you've provided `/usr/local/bin`? What is the output of `file /usr/local/bin/screenfetch`?

Comment: To add to the above, is there a reason you don't just install it with apt? It's in the repo and seems to work as expected when installed from the repo. It's just `sudo apt install screenfetch`

Comment: @Kulfy it is `/usr/local/bin/screenfetch: directory`

Comment: @KGIII yes it works with apt install but I try to figure out the /bin directory

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell looks for executables and scripts that reside in the folders specified in `PATH`. `bin` is an abbreviation of binaries and it should contain executables (which can be scripts as well), not folders containing executables. Consider moving executables out of the screenfetch folder. In short, currently in your system, the screenfetch script is in `/usr/local/bin/screenfetch/` but it should be in `/usr/local/bin`.

Alternatively, you can add `/usr/local/bin/screenfetch/` in `PATH` which would be make shell to look inside that folder too.

Comment: Yes I understand now. I have mv the script to `/usr/bin` and it works now. Thanks a lot !!

Comment: just want a quick answer because I afraid my new post will get duplicated. I had `useradd guest` and `passwd guest` as a root but I cannot log in from the waitng login computer screen. How do I solve this ?

Comment: @CoffeePlease Regarding the question, did you logged out from current account or just locked screen?

Comment: I have added guest user and then logged out from my current account by `gnome-session-quit --no-prompt`.

Comment: @CoffeePlease I'm not sure and if you have another question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](//askubuntu.com/questions/ask) button.